# Installed easy-rsa package, but I cannot find the directory

Tags: vpn, openvpn, certificates

I'm trying to set up OpenVPN, but I cannot generate certs due to not finding the easy-rsa directory.

The directory should be located here:

```
/usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/easy-rsa/
```

However, when I list the directories from .../openvpn/examples, I get this:

[image: easy-rsa missing]

I can't proceed without this directory. Please help.

Comment: NOTE: I am using a virtual box, if that is relevant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should install OpenVPN along with easy-rsa

```
sudo apt-get install openvpn easy-rsa
```

and copy over the Easy-RSA generation scripts

```
sudo cp -r /usr/share/easy-rsa /etc/openvpn
```

Comment: Since I had already installed OpenVPN and easy-rsa, I just did the copy operation, and it is now working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

After `sudo apt install openvpn easy-rsa`, do `make-cadir /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/`.

This will create the directory `/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/`.

Comment: it just creates an empty folder !

Comment: @bormat it's likely that you forgot to use sudo